# Will following tsconfig work for react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to figure out a setup for react-native and so far follwing tsconfig seems to work, am I missing something or using unnecessary bits? As this was mostly copied over from react. Can this be optimised for react-native more?

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es7"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "./typings"
        ],
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
        "./android",
        "./ios",
        "./assets",
        "./__tests__",
        "./dist"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ]
}
```